# Programmatically check Linux RAID array (MD)

Tags: linux, software-raid

I would like to programmatically check if Linux RAID arrays are broken.

For a RAID-1 (mirror) array, I am using this simple method which was worked for several years, with good results:

```
cat /proc/mdstat | grep "_" > /dev/null
EC=$?
```

The idea behind this is that **/proc/mdstat** shows `[UU]` if both hard-disks are OK, and `[U_]` if one has failed, `[__]` if both failed, etc.
Usually, the output of /proc/mdstat has no "_" inside, so it is working.

Now we have additionally have a RAID-0 (stripe) array. In **/proc/mdstat** it looks like this:

```
md2 : active linear sde1[0] sdf1[1]
      3906699440 blocks super 1.2 0k rounding
```

My question is, how can I detect if this RAID array is broken? How would mdstat look like?
(Note: I know that /dev/md2 will be destroyed when one of these disks fail, but I would like to programmatically check the RAID array instead of checking the virtual drive md2 for functionality)

OS is Debian 9.

Comment: the `mdadm` package has a ready solution for you, including e-mail notifications.

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes, I know this functionality. But I would like to query the status of all arrays with my own script, which has some additional logic (i.e. automatically stopping internal backups to safe the lifetime of the remaining disks).

Comment: `mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep -e '^\s*State : ' | awk '{ print $NF; }'` will output "clean" or "active" for a good array.

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint. Can you please post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While parsing `/proc/mdstat` i feasable, it becomes messy if you want to specialize on an array or want to cover different RAID levels and failure modes.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep -e '^\s*State : ' | awk '{ print $NF; }'
```

will output "clean" or "active" for a good array. You can also loop over `/dev/md/*` to get all arrays.

Comment: i have a raid1 on 3 disks. i see "clean" when it is fully nice. and "active, degraded, recovering" when one disk is nice, the second is removed/dead, and the third is recovering

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to query the disk states `cat /sys/block/md*/md/dev-*/state`.
It is easier, and it does not require super-user rights.

The possible values (can be comma separated) are described here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/md.html

Answer (score 1):

Had this recently,

```
dev="";sed 's/\(recovery\|finish\|speed\)/\n#     \0/g;s/^ /#/g' /proc/mdstat |grep -v -e "^# *$" -e "unused devices" -e ^Personalities |while read a ; do if [[ "$a" =~ ^#.*  ]]; then echo "$a"|sed 's/^# \+/'$dev" : "'/g'; else dev=$(echo "$a"|cut -d" " -f1);echo "$a";fi;done
```

outputs each line with device index in front . e.g.:

```
md2 : active raid1 sda5[2] sdb5[0]
md2 : 1948683456 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
md2 : [========>............]
md2 : recovery = 41.7% (813027392/1948683456)
md2 : finish=128.9min
md2 : speed=146824K/sec
md1 : active raid1 sda2[1] sdb2[0]
md1 : 2097088 blocks [2/2] [UU]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[1] sdb1[0]
md0 : 2490176 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

regards